# laravel 多次元配列の値の取り出しについて

Tags: php, laravel, array

現在Laravelにて開発中のアプリがありネストしたデータを一つの配列として扱いたいのですがやり方がわからなく困っています。

実現したい形は以下となります。
配列のデータは下記だと2件ですが100以上ある想定です。
ループで回して実現したいのですが、もしわかる方がいたらアドバイスお願いします。

・元データ

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => "0GPHKD"
    "target_layer" => "男女 10代(T層)"
    "key" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "id" => 10
        "product_name" => "コーヒー"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "id" => 9
        "product_name" => "コーヒーマグカップ"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => "0GPHKC"
    "target_layer" => "男女 20〜34歳(M1F1層)"
    "key" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "id" => 10
        "product_name" => "コーヒー"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "id" => 9
        "product_name" => "コーヒーマグカップ"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

・実現したい形

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => "0GPHKD"
    "target_layer" => "男女 10代(T層)"
    "item_id1" => "10"
    "product_name1" => "コーヒー"
     "item_id2" => "9"
    "product_name2" => "コーヒーマグカップ"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => "0GPHKC"
    "target_layer" => "男女 20〜34歳(M1F1層)"
 　   "item_id1" => "10"
    "product_name1" => "コーヒー"
     "item_id2" => "9"
    "product_name2" => "コーヒーマグカップ"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: 「わからない」とは具体的に何がわからないですか？配列のループの回し方ですか？それとも新しい配列の作り方ですか？ご自身が試したコードも載せていただけるとよいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

一番簡単なのはネストループを使って、新しい配列を作ります。
例えば下記のコードです。
サンプルデータ：

```
$a = [
    [
      "id" => "0GPHKD",
      "target_layer" => "男女 10代(T層)",
      "key" => [
        [
          "id" => 10,
          "product_name" => "コーヒー"
        ],
        [
          "id" => 9,
          "product_name" => "コーヒーマグカップ"
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => "0GPHKC",
      "target_layer" => "男女 20〜34歳(M1F1層)",
      "key" => [
        [
          "id" => 10,
          "product_name" => "コーヒー"
        ],
        [
          "id" => 9,
          "product_name" => "コーヒーマグカップ"
        ]
      ]
    ]
];
```

ネストループ：

```
$newList = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $new = [
        "id" => $val["id"],
        "target_layer" => $val["target_layer"],
    ];

    if (count($val["key"]) > 0) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($val["key"]); $i++) {
            $new["item_id".$i] = $val["key"][$i]["id"];
            $new["product_name".$i] = $val["key"][$i]["product_name"];
        }
    }

    array_push($newList, $new);
}
```

結果：

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0GPHKD
            [target_layer] => 男女 10代(T層)
            [item_id0] => 10
            [product_name0] => コーヒー
            [item_id1] => 9
            [product_name1] => コーヒーマグカップ
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0GPHKC
            [target_layer] => 男女 20〜34歳(M1F1層)
            [item_id0] => 10
            [product_name0] => コーヒー
            [item_id1] => 9
            [product_name1] => コーヒーマグカップ
        )

)
```